# kendo mobile data-bind base64 image to image tag

Tags: kendo-mobile

I have a viewModel containing a data object with 3 values in (name, age, photo). To get access to the data properties I can do data.name, data.age and data.photo.

I'm unable to show the photo in the img tag, but I can put it's contents into an input field. Any ideas?

In my view I have

```html
<div
    data-role="view" 
    data-layout="layout-customers"
    id="customer" 
    data-title="Customer"
    data-transition="slide:left"
    data-model="app.customer.viewModel"
    data-init="app.customer.init"
    data-show="app.customer.show">

    <form>
        <img data-bind="value: data.photo" src="data:image/png;base64"/>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: data.photo"/>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: data.name"/>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: data.age"/>
    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found one way of doing achieving this ...

I added the following lines of code to the function which is called by the view data-show ...

```js
//Get result here into result array
viewModel.set("data", result[0]);
var smallImage = $("#smallImage");
smallImage.attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + viewModel.data.photo);
```

**View**

```html
<img id="smallImage" src="" style="height:135px;"/>
```

Does anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a **Calculated field** to your VM, to create the string that the image expect.

lets say your VM look like this:

```js
var VM = kendo.observable({
    name: undefined,
    age: undefined,
    photo: undefined
});
```

so you can do:

```js
var VM = kendo.observable({
    name: undefined,
    age: undefined,
    photo: undefined,
    photoAsBase64: function()
    {
        return "data:image/jpeg;base64," + this.get('photo');
    }
});
```

then, you bind your image source to `photoAsBase64` with `attr`

```html
<img data-bind="attr: { src: data.photoAsBase64 }" />
```